Tracking Connected gRPC Clients and Sending Targeted Data
I have a gRPC server that i wrote base on asp.net core and a gRPC client built with MAUI for Android.
The client uses SocketsHttpHandler to send keep-alive pings to the server every 30 seconds.
How can I track connected clients on the server?
I want to store a unique identifier (like IP address) for each client and be able to send specific data to individual clients.

On any grpc function there is parameter ServerCallContext context
on this parameter context.Peer suppose to hold the ip address of the client
on this context you can also find the httpContext that contain also the ip and the unique id that the server gave to the client
